# How to keep app in portrait mode

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't seem to keep my app in portrait mode when I run it, I set supported device orientations to only portrait and it still rotates, all help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this to all your viewcontrollers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: I can still rotate to landscape mode.

Answer (score 3):

Write this in all the view controllers

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}
```

Also in the project-info.plist

change the values for the key

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientationss</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

To

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientationss</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

Comment: What he is saying is correct.  To expand a little more, sometimes when you set the device orientation after some files have been created, the old files to not autocorrect.  You must do this automatically.  All new files after these changes are made should be already correct.

Comment: this will give you one **NSLog** entry telling you to support at-least one orientation instead of just return NO use @Maxim Mikheev's answer for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method