# How do I keep my ios app in portrait mode at all times

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, orientation, autorotate

Where do I put shouldAutoRotate to keep my app in portrait mode at all times?

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutoRotat
{
     return NO;
}
```

I see only old, deprecated answers on stack overflow.

Comment: An easier way is just to uncheck all the modes except for portrait in the general settings of your app.

Comment: Check this one http://www.myuiviews.com/2014/03/27/handling-portrait-and-landscape-in-ios7-at-app-launch.html

Comment: i want to do it programmatically for all views

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep app in portrait mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873441/how-to-keep-app-in-portrait-mode)

Comment: the answered question is old and deprecated

Comment: where's settings if you don't have a storyboard

Comment: negative 1 with no explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AppDelegate, add the following

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:
(UIWindow *)window
{       
    /*if([viewManager.currentView isSupportRotate]) 
    {
          return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }*/
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

You can also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for some special views which can be rotated.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan answered the question correctly. But i didn't understand why he mentioned viewManager part. Instead we can write is simple

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

Comment: Just in case you don't want every view in portrait. viewManager is a sample record the view for your App. You can ignore viewManager if you want every view in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Targets and in General -->Deployment Info , Go to "Device Orientation" and set As per your Requirement(in your case just select Portrait).[image]

Comment: Cool that's where it is, I know I saw it

Comment: If it's salve your que, then you can accept it as correct for reference of others.